# WMI: How can I fix the port?

Tags: windows, firewall, port, wmi

I need to use WMI for getting some information from my servers. But I have a server in DMZ, so I need to open a port in my firewall. I've searching and I found that WMI uses random port.
How can this be fixed?

Comment: What OS is installed on a DMZ server?

Comment: Hi, it's Windows server 2003, 2008 and Seven.

Answer (score 1):

The following procedure is an automated setup to allow WMI to have a fixed port. The procedure uses the winmgmt command-line tool.
To set up a fixed port for WMI

1. At the command prompt, type winmgmt -standalonehost
2. Stop the WMI service by typing the command net stop "Windows Management Instrumentation"
3. Restart the WMI service again in a new service host by typing net start "Windows Management Instrumentation"
4. Establish a new port number for the WMI service by typing netsh firewall add portopening TCP 24158 WMIFixedPor

Comment: shikran, I've already test this manipulation but it doesn't change anything. For information, I use Splunk for getting log files.

Answer (score 0):

from http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverManagement/thread/c2ca4979-165a-4bb9-903c-e23f6a35dbf1/

> On the *responding* machine... Step one:  Set the DCOM config to use a
>   static port.... Basically, run "dcomcnfg" from command prompt.
>   Navigate the tree to My Computer > DCOM Config > Windows Management
>   and Instrumentation, select properties of that folder. Go to the
>   Endpoints tab Select Properties button for Connection-oriented TCP/IP
>   Use static endpoint, set the port. Step 2:  Configure WMI to use a
>   fixed port
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219447(v=VS.85).aspx At the
>   command prompt, type winmgmt -standalonehost Stop the WMI service by
>   typing the command net stop "Windows Management Instrumentation"
>   Restart the WMI service again in a new service host by typing net
>   start "Windows Management Instrumentation" Establish a new port number
>   for the WMI service by typing netsh firewall add portopening TCP 24158
>   WMIFixedPort Still testing this myself, so not 100% certain it works.

There is more information in other comments

Comment: Fixed port cannot be set on a Windows Server 2003 machine. This option appeared starting from Windows Vista.

"...Starting with Windows Vista, you can set up the WMI service to run as the only process in a separate host and specify a fixed port."
Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219447(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To be able to collect information from remote host via WMI, you need to do the following:

**1. Enable remote WMI requests**

1.1. On the target server, go to `Administrative Tools` -> `Computer Management`.

1.2. Expand `'Services and Applications'`.

1.3. Right click for **Properties** on `'WMI Control'`.

1.4. Select the **Security** tab.

1.5. Press the **Security** button.

1.6. Add the monitoring user (if needed), and then be sure to check **Remote Enable** check-box for the user/group that will be requesting WMI data.

**2. Allow WMI through Windows Firewall**

This can only be done at the command prompt. Run the following on the target computer if it is running a Windows firewall:

*on Windows Server 2003 machines*

```
 netsh firewall set service RemoteAdmin enable
```

*on Windows Server 2008 machines*

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes
```

More details can be found [here](http://www.poweradmin.com/help/enableWMI.aspx).
Articles on MSDN with more in-depth view [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) & [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa822854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi, I don't have a local firewall on the PCs but a network firewall, so it's why I need fixe a WMI port for open it.

Comment: You'd better mention this next time in your question. In such situation, you can only setup fixed port on a Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7 machines, but not W2K3 server. Follow this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219447(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry for that. I've already did this manipulation, but my Splunk Server use always random port for WMI.